404 not found error when updating name of a category in laravel 11
I'm making an e-commerce store in Laravel 11. it has categories you can add or edit the name of the categories. when i try to edit and then press update on the category name it gives me 404 not found error. I'm using xampp
routes

Route::controller(CategoryController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::get('/admin/all-category', 'index')->name('allcategory');
    Route::get('/admin/add-category', 'ADDcategory')->name('addcategory');
    Route::post('/admin/store-category', 'StoreCategory')->name('storecategory');
    Route::get('/admin/edit-category/{id}','EditCategory')->name('editcategory');
    Route::post('/admin/update-category/','UpdateCategory')->name('updatecategory');
    

});

controller
 public function EditCategory($id){
    
        $category_info = Category::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.editcategory', compact('category_info'));
    }


    public function UpdateCategory(Request $request){
        $category_id = $request->category_id;

        $request->validate([

            'category_name' => 'required|unique:categories'

        ]);

        Category::findOrFail($category_id)->update([

            'category_name' => $request->category_name,
            'slug' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $request->category_name))

        ]);

        return redirect()->route('allcategory')->with('message', 'category updated successfully!');


    }
}

blade php
<form action="{{ route('updatecategory') }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $category_info->id }}" name="category_id>"
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="basic-default-name">Category Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_name" name="category_name"
                                    name="category_name" value="{{ $category_info->category_name }}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

i tried searching online , but didn't get any
